# How can I pass a generic struct to a function in C?

Tags: c, struct

I'm beginner in C programming and I have a doubt about to pass a generic struct to a function in C.

Here is what I have:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    float price;
} product;

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int type;
} category;
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
void changeName(struct *s, newName[20]) {
    strcpy(s->name, newName);
}
```

If someone has already asked that, please disconsider this and sends me the issue link.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The function's name is missing

Comment: Generics programming is simply not a thing in C.

Comment: In C++, you could use a template.  In C, you need to 1: give a name to your function, 2. define 2 separate functions, one for each type.  3. You could use a macro to provide the functionality, but that's not recommended.

Comment: try `void changeName(void *s, char newName[20]) {
    strcpy((char*)s,  newName);
}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What happens if `name` is not the first member of the struct?

Comment: I have forgot the function's name, my bads :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that idea if chock full of assumptions, and is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Of course, it is a premise that it is the first member.

Comment: That's not the premise of generic programming.  A macro would be much safer to use, so would strncpy_s(), in this particular case.

Comment: As I need something basic, the @BLUEPIXY solution already helps me. But I will look for other solutions also to improve my knowledge

Comment: @Frank What is your assumptions?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY main one being that no one will add a member to that struct In 6 months from now. It's the equivalent of a programming land mine. Almost anything that relies on struct member ordering is.

Comment: @Frank Indeed, but that seems to be a different problem in this post. In that case, it is necessary to specify that it assumes change.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm just talking about your (in my opinion bad) suggestion to void-cast to one of the structs.

Comment: @Frank With the assumption of the current OP, that is no problem. I premise the OP code.  I am not assuming the future of OP code. That is OP's job.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY And I feel that OP had a right to know that your suggested solution, while functional, is bad software engineering. I agree I shouldn't have handwaved your code away without explanation, and I'm glad you prompted me to explain. It's all cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a `union`

One approach would be to add a structure containing a `union`, itself containing pointers to `product` and `category` structures, as well as an `enum` to identify the type of data in the `struct`. This `union`, or a pointer to it, could be passed to a `change_name()` function.

Here is an example that would work in C11. It uses an unnamed `union` member, so this is not valid C99 code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    float price;
} product;

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int type;
} category;

typedef struct {
    enum { PRODUCT, CATEGORY } type;
    union {
        product *prod;
        category *cat;
    };
} generic;

void change_name(generic *gen, const char *new_name);

int main(void)
{
    product prod_a = { .name = "widget", .price = 1.99 };
    category cat_a = { .name = "general", .type = 1 };
    generic gen_prod_a = { .type = PRODUCT, .prod = &prod_a };
    generic gen_cat_a = { .type = CATEGORY, .cat = &cat_a };

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.name);

    change_name(&gen_prod_a, "gadget");
    change_name(&gen_cat_a, "specific");

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.name);

    return 0;
}

void change_name(generic *gen, const char *new_name)
{
    switch (gen->type) {
    case PRODUCT:
        strcpy(gen->prod->name, new_name);
        break;
    case CATEGORY:
        strcpy(gen->cat->name, new_name);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown type in change_name()\n");
    }
}
```

This could be made to work in C99 by naming the `union`:

```
typedef struct {
    enum { PRODUCT, CATEGORY } type;
    union {
        product *prod;
        category *cat;
    } data;                                  // named for C99
} generic;

/* ... */

generic gen_prod_a = { .type = PRODUCT, .data.prod = &prod_a };
generic gen_cat_a = { .type = CATEGORY, .data.cat = &cat_a };

/* ... */

void change_name(generic *gen, const char *new_name)
{
    switch (gen->type) {
    case PRODUCT:
        strcpy(gen->data.prod->name, new_name);
        break;
    case CATEGORY:
        strcpy(gen->data.cat->name, new_name);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown type in change_name()\n");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, one `struct` type could hold an `enum` identifier and a `union` containing the product and category structures. This approach may seem a bit more streamlined:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    enum { PRODUCT, CATEGORY } type;
    union {
        struct {
            char name[20];
            float price;
        } prod;
        struct {
            char name[20];
            int type;
        } cat;
    } data;
} record;

void change_name(record *rec, const char *new_name);

int main(void)
{
    record prod_a = { .type = PRODUCT };
    change_name(&prod_a, "widget");
    prod_a.data.prod.price = 1.99;

    record cat_a = { .type = CATEGORY };
    change_name(&cat_a, "general");
    cat_a.data.cat.type = 1;

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.data.prod.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.data.cat.name);

    change_name(&prod_a, "gadget");
    change_name(&cat_a, "specific");

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.data.prod.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.data.cat.name);

    return 0;
}

void change_name(record *rec, const char *new_name)
{
    switch (rec->type) {
    case PRODUCT:
        strcpy(rec->data.prod.name, new_name);
        break;
    case CATEGORY:
        strcpy(rec->data.cat.name, new_name);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown type in change_name()\n");
    }
}
```

### Using a type-generic macro

Both of the above approaches are a little bit awkward. Another solution, available for C11 only, is to use the `_Generic` keyword in a type-generic macro. Here, functions are written for each expected data type, and a macro selects which function definition is to be used based on type. A virtue of this approach is that as new types are added, only new functions and updates to the type-generic macro are needed to handle them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define change_name(S, N) _Generic ((S),                                \
                                    prod_ptr: change_name_prod,         \
                                    cat_ptr: change_name_cat            \
                                   )((S), (N))

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    float price;
} product;

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int type;
} category;

typedef product *prod_ptr;
typedef category *cat_ptr;

void change_name_prod(product *prod, const char *new_name);
void change_name_cat(category *cat, const char *new_name);

int main(void)
{
    product prod_a = { .name = "widget", .price = 1.99 };
    category cat_a = { .name = "general", .type = 1 };

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.name);

    change_name(&prod_a, "gadget");
    change_name(&cat_a, "specific");

    printf("prod_a.name = %s\n", prod_a.name);
    printf("cat_a.name = %s\n", cat_a.name);

    return 0;
}

void change_name_prod(product *prod, const char *new_name)
{
    strcpy(prod->name, new_name);
}

void change_name_cat(category *cat, const char *new_name)
{
    strcpy(cat->name, new_name);
}
```

All of the above programs have the same output:

```
prod_a.name = widget
cat_a.name = general
prod_a.name = gadget
cat_a.name = specific
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already typedef-ed the structures. You can use these other names.

For example, if the name is `product`, first create a variable and call the function

```
product var={"name", 1.2};
changeName(&var, "AnotherName");
```

Then pass this variable to a function

```
void changeName(product *s, char newName[])
{
    strcpy(s->name, newName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generic programming, which implies type-safety just doesn't really exist in C.  But there are ways around that.

What I understand from your question, is 'Can I define a function that can be applied to common elements of different structures?

Let's expand you example a bit, to have items which share a common trait.

```
struct info
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
};

struct product
{
   Info info;
   int price;
};

struct category
{
   Info info;
   int type;
};
```

You can now define a function that would work safely on the traits shared by both product and category.

```
void changeName(info* p, const char* name)
{
    strcpy_s(info->name, sizeof(info->name), name);
}

int main()
{
    category cat;
    product prod;
    memset(&cat, 0, sizeof(cat));
    memset(&prod, 0, sizeof(prod));

    changeName(&cat.info, "Category 1");
    changeName(&prod.info, "blue product");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code has quite a few errors and will not compile.